# How to select all elements with an attribute that starts with

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select all the elements that start with the "box". This is my existing code:

```
if (($(this).attr('title') == 'Box a') || ($(this).attr('title') == 'Box b')) || ($(this).attr('title') == 'Box c')) {
// do stuff
 }
```

Is there a way to shorten this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS symbols it is possible!

The `^` symbol.

`$(element[title^='box']);`

That selects all `element` elements that the title field starts with `box`.

UPDATE:

Try this.

```
var regEx = /^Box/;

if(regEx.test($(this).attr('title'))){

}
```

Comment: Ah yes, but if I want to use (this), how would it work in that syntax?

Answer (score 0):

you could use :

```
$('[title^=box]')
```

Or, to simplify your search, you could do this,

```
var title = $(this).attr('title').replace("Box ", "");
if(['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(title) != -1)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

**Explanation :**

- `replace` is a JS function which will replace any string you send as parameter1 with the second parameter. Here, I'm replacing "Box " (space included) to "", pratically deleting that from string and closing it. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- `['a','b','c']` is an array. To search in that array, you can `indexOf`. If the function returns `-1`, it means, that the title doesn't have that a or b or c in it. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

But, if you want to just check if element's title starts with "Box", you could simply do this:

```
 var title = $(this).attr('title').split(" ")[0]; //this would give you "Box" alone
 if(title.indexOf("Box") != -1)
 {
      //do stuff
 }
```

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: That might work! But can you tell me why you used replace? I looked it up on jQuery and couldn't find the documentation for that function. And why would the result be -1?

Comment: the search code would _erroneously_ match an element with title `a` since it simply _strips_ the `Box ` prefix rather than test for it.